# Not able to redirect to MAUI app after google Authentication

Tags: maui, mobile-development

I am trying to implement google authentication in my MAUI app and following this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication)

```
 var response = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(new WebAuthenticatorOptions()
 {
     Url = new Uri(authUrl),
     CallbackUrl = new Uri(callbackUrl)
 });
```

activity class:

```
[Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter([Intent.ActionView],
    Categories = [Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable], DataScheme = "https")]
public class WebAuthenticatorActivity : WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity//BrowserTabActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

I am able to get the browser but after successful login the browser does not close in my android emulator.

Comment: You can check this [Configure the Android app for authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/maui/authentication#configure-the-android-app-for-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnActivityResult`, The MsalActivity traps the redirect URL, which then switches back to the main activity by calling OnActivityResult(). The OnActivityResult() method calls the MSAL authentication helper to complete the transaction.

```
#if ANDROID
            events.AddAndroid(platform =>
            {
                platform.OnActivityResult((activity, rc, result, data) =>
                {
                    AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(rc, result, data);
                });
            });
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where should I write this. Could you please explain. Thanks